# Reduce SQL Server Database Size

Tags: sql-server

I ran the following script to get the size of all the tables in my database

```
SELECT   t.NAME AS TableName,  i.name AS indexName,  SUM(p.rows) AS RowCounts,  
SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages,   SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages,   SUM(a.data_pages)
AS DataPages,  
(SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS TotalSpaceMB,   (SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS
UsedSpaceMB, (SUM(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 AS DataSpaceMB
FROM   sys.tables t INNER JOIN    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id 
INNER JOIN   sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN   sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id 
WHERE  t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND  i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
AND    i.index_id <= 1 
GROUP BY   t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name  ORDER BY   OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id)
```

Many tables showed a large difference in the TotalSpaceMB and UsedSpaceMB columns. The total of the TotalSpaceMB = 7.6GB while the total of UsedSpaceMB = 1.1 GB. 
e.g.: TableName: BOMS 
RowCount: 72747 
Total Pages: 183960 
Used Pages: 23999   
Data Pages: 21752   
TotalSpaceMB: 1437  
UsedSpaceMB: 187
DataSpace MB: 169

My data is also not that big to warrant a size of > 7GB.

What could be the reason for such a large difference in the total size in MB and used size in MB and is there a method to reduce the total size in MB?

Just shrinking the database using SQL Management Studio did not help.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reason for such a large difference in the total size in MB and used size in MB

- There was data at one time.
- Someone created the database with rserves in mind because hey, expanding is a costly operation.

And - which file? Your sum is irrelevant if for example most space is in log files - then it could be a problem cleaning them up.

Comment: The total 7.6 GB space has been taken up by the .mdf file. the log file is very small (around 12MB).

Comment: Then i wuold bet at precaution. It is good practice NOT to let database files grow on their own on production machines.

Comment: Ok..right now the autogrowth option on the files is set to: "By 10% unrestricted growth". Is there any way to rectify the setting and reduce the size of the data file

Comment: Sure - change the setting. Reduce the data file size? There is a point in server manager that you can to do make this. r schedule a task.